# .live() or .livequery()

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a site that is Ajaxed, content that is Ajax is from other pages, such as about.html, contact.html. The ajax is getting the content from a div called #main-content. But after the ajax call, rest of my scripts break. Such as the tinyscrollbar() plugin and some other custom functions.

I searched for about 4 days and found out that my problem was the AJAX request changing the DOM, and since scripts being loaded before that, it doesn't run after the ajax call.

If i'm right, what would I need to fix this? .live() or the .livequery() plugin?

All the JS I am using is in this:

```
var $dd = $('.projects dl').find('dd'), $defBox = $('#def-box');

  $defBox.hide();
  $('.projects').hover(function(){
    $defBox.stop(true, true)
      .fadeToggle(1000)
      .html('<p>Hover The links to see a description</p>');
  });

  $dd.hide();
  $('.projects dl dt').hover(function(){
    var $data = $(this).next('dd').html();
    $defBox.html($data);
    }); 

  // Ajax Stuff 
  // Check for hash value in URL  
  var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);

  //  Check to ensure that a link with href == hash is on the page  
  if ($('a[href="' + hash + '"]').length) {
    //  Load the page.
    var toLoad = hash + '.php #main-content';
    $('#main-content').load(toLoad);
  }

  $("nav ul li a").click(function(){
    var goingTo = $(this).attr('href');
    goingTo = goingTo.substring(goingTo.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    if (window.location.hash.substring(1) === goingTo) return false;

    var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #main-content',
    $content = $('#main-content'), $loadimg = $('#load');

    $content.fadeOut('fast',loadContent);  
      $loadimg.remove();  
      $content.append('<span id="load"></span>');  
      $loadimg.fadeIn('slow');  
    window.location.hash = goingTo;

    function loadContent() {  
        $content.load(toLoad,'',showNewContent)  
    }  
    function showNewContent() {  
        $content.fadeIn('fast',hideLoader);  
    }  
    function hideLoader() {  
        $loadimg.fadeOut('fast');  
    }  
    return false;  

  });
```

Comment: You should usually prefer .delegate() over .live(), it's more performant. Also, I don't think there is a lot livequery can do that .live or delegate can't now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For plugins, neither really. You can simply re-init your plugins within `$.load`'s complete callback:

```
$('#main-content').load(toLoad, function() {
    $("#foo").tinyscrollbar();
    $("#bar").facebox();
    // etc
});
```

For event handlers, you can rebind them within the callback as in the above example, or use `.live` or `.delegate` (which you already seem to be using) to ensure that the binding persists for future (ajax-replaced) elements, e.g.:

```
$('.projects dl').delegate("dt", "hover", function() {
   ...
}, function() {
    ...
});
```

or:

```
$('.projects dl dt').live("hover", function() {
   ...
}, function() {
    ...
});
```

Comment: Really? Load all of my scripts under .load()?

Comment: @Trippy - the `complete` callback fires once the response has been inserted into the DOM. You can simply call the plugins on the elements in there - so every time you replace elements in the container you are immediately attaching your plugins/event handlers to them. Try it out :)

Comment: Okay I can call the plugins what about the others such as $('.projects dl dt').hover(function(){
    ......
    });

Comment: @Trippy - I have edited. Simply replace your existing event handlers with `.delegate` ones (preferred) or `.live` ones (not as performant).

Comment: Alright i'm getting it now, kinda. Could you explain what would I put in the first and second function() function() {
   What goes here?
}, function() {
    and here?
});

Sorry i'm kinda a newbie with ajax and these.

Comment: @Trippy - From your comment I had assumed that you already have a `.hover` handler somewhere :) The first function handlers the mouseenter event, the second handlers the mouseleave event. [Hover docs](http://api.jquery.com/hover/).

Comment: Oh kay... {
   Mouseenter
}, function() {
    mouseleave
});

Right? and then $('#main-content').load(toLoad, function(){
tinyscrollbar();
});

Comment: @Trippy - sounds about right. I will be away from my computer for an hour or so, if you need any more help just drop some comments here, I will check them once I get back.

Comment: would it make since to make the events into functions and then calling it in .load()? $('#main-content').load(toLoad, function(){ defbox(); }); as in example.