# How to get .delegate() to work

Tags: jquery, ajax

[I asked this question the other day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914486/live-or-livequery/4914509#4914509) and found out I should use .delegate() to get jquery to work after the ajax call, but I can't figure out how to do it. Ajax just stops working altogether after I tried

So I tried:

```
$('.projects').hover(function(){
    $defBox.stop(true, true)
      .fadeToggle(1000)
      .html('<p>Hover The links to see a description</p>');
  });
```

and changed it to this:

```
$('.projects').delegate($defBox, "hover", function(){
    $defBox.stop(true, true)
      .fadeToggle(1000)
      .html('<p>Hover The links to see a description</p>');
  });
```

and:

```
$('.projects dl').delegate($defBox, "hover", function() {
   .fadeIn(1000);
}, function() {
    fadeOut(1000);
});
```

Both still didn't work.  Anything i'm doing wrong?

Also this doesn't work ether.

```
    $('#main-content').load(toLoad, function() {
    $("#foo").tinyscrollbar();
    $("#bar").facebox();
    // etc
});
```

Comment: What's up with .fadeIn(`1000); and .fadeOut(`1000);?  Those backticks don't belong.  Typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say without seeing your markup, but since you're loading into `main-container`, I'm guessing you want this:

```
$('#main-container').delegate('.projects', 'hover', function(){
    // and so on
```

Now the hover events (mouseenter/mouseleave) will fire for `.projects` elements that are inside `#main-container` regardless of when they're added.

Comment: So I should select the wrapper thats loading everything in it and then delegate it?

Comment: @Trippy, if I'm understanding you, yes. The way `.delegate()` works is that it gets placed on a container. When elements inside the container receive an event, the element gets compared to the `.projects` selector (in this case). If the element matched the selector, then handler is invoked.

Comment: Alright I will try this later on, but one more question, can I just change .hover() to ,delegate and not add another function? As in, is this reqired? ' function() {
   .fadeIn(`1000);
}, function() { '

Comment: @Trippy: `.delegate()` can only accept 1 function. It will fire the same handler for the mouseenter/mouseleave events. If you need to run different code for each event, then you need to test the `event.type`.

Comment: @patrick dw it doesn't work, it even stops the ajax from working.

Comment: @Trippy here is a JSFiddle demonstrating patricks's suggestion. I've also added some Ajax into the mix. Hope this helps. http://www.jsfiddle.net/subhaze/VDsmM/